# Why does my Navigation Bar temporarily disappear when I dismiss a modal view in iOS 7?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, ios7

When I'm going back from my Modal View Controller to my Main View Controller (I have a horizontal animation) my Main Controllers navbar places itself a bit too high for a quick second and then jumps back to its right position. Does somebody know why? Ive been googling it but with no success.

App Delegate:

```
 [navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
 [navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent: NO];
```

When i push button to open my Info View:

```
UIViewController *infoViewController;
infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle: nil];
infoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController: infoViewController animated: YES completion:nil];
```

I'm not using Auto Layout on any xib-files. My Main View Controller xib-file is empty with Status Bar: Default. My Info View Controller xib-file has some stuff in it.

Code for closing my Modal View Controller:

```
-(IBAction)onBackBtnClick:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

Comment: are you calling [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES/NO] at any point?

Comment: No! :/ thats why i'm confused

Comment: We're going to need more context. Post some code. How are you dismissing the view controller? Are you using AutoLayout? If so, what are your constraints?

Comment: I have the same problem when i modal a new view.

Comment: Please tell me if you solve the problem!

Answer (score 3):

All what you have to do is to add the following code in the ViewWillAppear of the "InfoViewController" viewController class

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

Hope it worked with you :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be

```
infoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

If you change this to

```
infoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

then it will no longer jump.  This worked for me.  Good luck!